# Form rules don't work

Tags: php, validation, yii2

My controller:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['text'], 'required', 'message' => 'Fill in this field'],
        ['text', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'message' => 'Too short message'],
        ['text', 'validateUser']
    ];
}
public function validateUser($attribute)
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        $this->addError($attribute, 'You must be logged in');
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1) Instead of the message 'Too short message' i see 'text field should contain at least 6 characters.'

2) validateUser not added a warning 'You must be logged in'

Comment: [['text'], 'required', 'message' => 'Fill in this field'],
why you put 'text' into [ ] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad1. It should be `['text', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'tooShort' => 'Too short message'],`

Ad2. Are you sure this condition is true? Can you use `die()` here or something like that? Or this validation rule isn't even activated?

Comment: This rule is not activated

Comment: And text length is more then 6 right? If first validation rule isn't passed the second wouldn't be activated unless you add `'skipOnError' => false`

Answer (score 0):

**For validateUser**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['text'], 'required', 'message' => 'Fill in this field'],
        ['text', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'message' => 'Too short message'],
        ['text', 'required', 'when' => function($model){
              return (Yii::$app->user->isGuest);
            },'message'=>'You must be logged in'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` is boolean so it would be better to write simply `return Yii::$app->user->isGuest`

Comment: Ok. Mr @PatrykRadziszewski. You said right. Thanks. Learnt.